# ruby activerecord easy one: call attribute by variable

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I want to update an attribute defined by a variable in an activerecord model.

This is my method

```
def increment_attribute(attr_name)
  self.attribute(attr_name).increment
end
```

This doesn't work because attribute is a private activerecord method

How should I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def increment_attribute(name)
  self.send(name).increment
end
```